# MySQL VBA Connection String with "NO_DATE_OVERFLOW"

Tags: mysql, vba, odbc

So I have this issue with MySQL linked tables in MS Access:
When I manually set up an ODBC Unicode connection with "Disable Date Overflow error" I'm able to delete records in the MySQL linked table using the MS Access front end.
[MySQL ODBC Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQevS.png)
However, when I connect using the below connection string in VBA the tables are connected but when I enter a date in the date field or try to delete a record I get a Date Overflow error

```
''-------------------------------------
strConn = "Driver={" & MysqlDriver & "}" & _
           ";server=" & ServerName & _
           ";Database=" & DatabaseName & _
           ";Trusted_Connection=Yes" & _
           ";NO_DATE_OVERFLOW=1" & _  'This is the part that I think it doesn't work in the code
           ";charset=utf8" & _
           ";user=" & ConnUserName & _
           ";password=" & ConnPassword

Delete_ALL_TABLES   '' Delete All the old tables before the import
Conn.Open strConn
Debug.Print Conn.ConnectionString
Set TablesSchema = Conn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
Debug.Print TablesSchema.RecordCount
Do While Not TablesSchema.EOF
 R = R + 1
 def_str = TablesSchema("TABLE_NAME")
 Debug.Print R, def_str
 Set tdfLink = db.CreateTableDef(def_str)
 tdfLink.SourceTableName = def_str
 tdfLink.Connect = "ODBC;" & strConn
 db.TableDefs.Append tdfLink
 DoEvents
 TablesSchema.MoveNext
Loop
''-------------------------------------
```

[MS Access Date Overflow Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExSun.png)

I'm using MySQL ODBC Unicode 8.0 driver and tested the connection with MS Access 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

it only works with the ODBC I manually create with "Disable Date Overflow error" checked.

Would you please help me fix the issue with the connection string?

Bouns help if I can save the password within the connection string so I don't have to import the tables when the MS Access Front end is closed and reopened.

Thank you in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the bonus. MS Access has an undocumented connection pool. If you create a connection, and later you try to access the same server & database using the same odbc driver main version, then it will reuse that connection, even if you are trying to use different credentials.
Side effect: if you create a DAO connection to the server and database where you have linked tables, they will work without prompting for user and password.

Also, from a security point of view, linked tables can be imported from an accde file into an editable accdb, so it is better to save the tables without user & password, and prompt the user for credentials once at startup. A less secure variation is when you hide the connection string in a VBA function, and you distribute an accde file. So an attacker has to disassemble the accde file to get the password. It can be done, but it stops most non-professionals.

So my proposal is to create a startup function, wich tries to create connections using all the odbc drivers on a list until it finds one, and than relinks  tables & passtrough queries only if the driver has been changed.

I'm using this to relink tables: (works with NO_DATE_OVERFLOW)

```
Private Sub dsnless_table2(Name As String, strconn As String, Optional srcname As String = "", Optional myflags As Long = 0)
'
On Error GoTo myerr
ERT = "dsnless_table2"
ert2 = ert2 & " ->" & ERT
ert3 = ""

   Dim tdef As New TableDef, sourcename As String, mysource As String, db As DAO.Database, eflag As Boolean, oldcon As String
   Set db = CurrentDb
   
eflag = False
On Error Resume Next
   If IsObject(db.TableDefs(Name)) = True Then eflag = True
   If err.Number <> 0 Then eflag = False
err.Clear
On Error GoTo myerr

If eflag = True Then
   sourcename = db.TableDefs(Name).SourceTableName
   oldcon = db.TableDefs(Name).Connect
   
   If compdiff(oldcon, strconn) = False And compdiff(sourcename, srcname) = False Then GoTo skip ' .Connect, .Name and .SourcetableName is equal to new value..
   ' else: recreate table; .Connect is write protected(?) after tabledefs.append
   DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, Name
   db.TableDefs.Refresh
Else
   sourcename = ""
End If
      
   If Len(srcname) = 0 Then
      If Len(sourcename) > 0 Then
         mysource = sourcename
      Else
         mysource = Name
      End If
   Else
      mysource = srcname
   End If
   
   Set tdef = db.CreateTableDef(Name, 0, mysource, strconn)  
   db.TableDefs.Append tdef  

' db.TableDefs.Append stores actual connection string instead of the specified one. 
   If tdef.Connect <> strconn Then
      tdef.Connect = strconn
      tdef.RefreshLink
   End If
   
skip:
On Error Resume Next
db.TableDefs(Trim(Name)).Properties("Attributes").Value = myflags ' dbHiddenObject ' 536870913  ' dbsystemobject = -2147483646
err.Clear
On Error GoTo myerr
   
   'db.TableDefs.Refresh
   
Exit Sub
'Resume Next
myerr:
    Call show_ert(err.Number, erl)
   
End Sub




Public Function compdiff(inA As Variant, inB As Variant) As Boolean
' returns true if values doesn't match, Including Null <>2 etc.. ' Null,Null --> False.  Null, 1 --> True. 1,1 --> False. A,B --> True.
'input: anything if "=" has a meaning for that datatype.
On Error GoTo myerr

Dim OneNullflag As Boolean, Compflag As Boolean
OneNullflag = IsNull(inA) Xor IsNull(inB) 'csak az egyik Null?
Compflag = Not (IsNull(inA) Or IsNull(inB)) 'egyik sem Null?

If OneNullflag = True Then
   compdiff = True ' Null <> 2
Else
   If Compflag = True Then
      ' No Nulls
      If inA = inB Then
         compdiff = False ' 1=1 ; (1<>1) = False
      Else
         compdiff = True ' 1<>2
      End If
   Else
      compdiff = False ' Null = Null
   End If
End If

Exit Function
myerr:
   ERT = "compdiff()"
   ert2 = ert2 & " ->" & ERT
   ert3 = ""
   Call show_ert(err.Number, erl)
End Function
```

And this is the function to create the connection:

```
Private Function dsntest(strCnn1 As Variant) As Boolean
' used by cnn_startup()
On Error GoTo myerr

   dsntest = False
   If IsNull(strCnn1) Then Exit Function
   If Len(CStr(strCnn1)) < 2 Then Exit Function

Dim dbs As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rn As Long

   Set dbs = CurrentDb()
   Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")
   
   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
   qdf.Connect = strCnn1
   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.
   qdf.SQL = "Select 0;" '"SET @icon = 1;" ' doesn't run on Oracle server --> sqlstr parameter
   
   On Error Resume Next
     qdf.Execute
     rn = err.Number
   On Error GoTo myerr
   
   If rn = 0 Then dsntest = True

cleanup:
   Set qdf = Nothing
   Set dbs = Nothing
   
   Exit Function
   
myerr:
   dsntest = False
   ERT = "dsntest"
   ert2 = ert2 & " ->" & ERT
   ert3 = ""
   Call show_ert(err.Number, erl)
   GoTo cleanup
End Function
```

We basically create a passtrough query wich opens the connection, than we throw it away, so there will not be any saved queries with the password.

Bonus info: I recommend to use odbc driver version 8.0.26. 8.0.29 might work with NO_DATE_OVERFLOW=1. See this for further details: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107235. 0.27 and 0.28 have other Access related bugs.

Bonus info 2: MS Access VBA has a half way documented erl object. I have a line numbering function that I run during the release process. If an error occurs on a numbered VBA line, it will be stored in the erl until you leave the sub/function or you clear the error. Show_ert() sends some telemetry data including erl to the server, so I can monitor client side errors.